# Second degree parabola

Tags: regression, self-study

Find a second degree parabola to the following data with 1999 as origin

Years 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001

Value 10   17   28   43   62

(b) What would be the equation of the second degree parabola when origin is shifted to 2001?

I HAVE PROBLEM WITH (b) part. How to shift?

Comment: mark this home work

Comment: Please see the discussion of homework-style questions in the [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's a second degree parabola, but the parabola is $y=a+bx+cx^2$

For your question they want an origin in 1999, so it's $y=a+b(x-1999)+c(x-1999)^2$